# PHP: Can't delete files created with fopen()?

Tags: php, unix

When I create a file using `fopen('filename.php', 'w+')` the file is created successfully BUT then I can't delete this file later on, no matter if I try deleting it with PHP or FTP.

Note: the created file's owner\group is '99' (nobody).

Comment: And what user does the web server run as? And what are the files permissions? The web server user must have write perms.

Comment: Are you calling `fclose($handle)` before trying to delete ? please show us the code.